# Navigation Helper SaveState / LoadState works incorrect

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

First, I read a list of entries from a database and display it in a ListView. When I leave the page to show details of an entry, then go back to the list, everything is ok.

Next, I open another page to add one entry to the database.

Go back to the list, reading from database shows me the correct count.

When I go to display one detail, the correct count is stored in SaveState.

Go back to the list, LoadState give the wrong count. It's the former state.

Display other details and go back now works with the old list and do not show me the added entry.

This is my code:

```
    private void getList()
    {
        memoList = new List<MemoItem>();
        db.loadHistory(ref memoList);
        DelButton.IsEnabled = false;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetList, memoList[{0}]", memoList.Count);
    }

    private void NavigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (memoList != null)
        {
            e.PageState["MemoItem"] = memoList;
            if (memoSelected > -1)
                e.PageState["memoSelected"] = memoSelected;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SaveState, memoList[{0}]", memoList.Count);
        }
    }

    private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PageState != null)
        {
            if (e.PageState.ContainsKey("MemoItem"))
            {
                memoList = (List<MemoItem>)e.PageState["MemoItem"];
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LoadState, memoList[{0}]", memoList.Count);
                if (e.PageState.ContainsKey("memoSelected"))
                    memoSelected = (int)e.PageState["memoSelected"];
                MemoListView.ItemsSource = memoList;
                MemoListView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                getList();
                showList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are the Systems.Diagnostic outputs with comments in ():

GetList, memoList[8] (first time loaded)

SaveState, memoList[8] (leave the list to display details for one entry)

LoadState, memoList[8] (come back to the ListView)

SaveState, memoList[8] (leave the list to another page and add one entry)

GetList, memoList[9] (back to the list, read the correct entry count from database)

SaveState, memoList[9] (leave the ListView to display details for one entry)

LoadState, memoList[8] (come back to the ListView loads the wrong old list)

SaveState, memoList[8] (and works with the old list...)

LoadState, memoList[8] (...)

Remark: I can't call GetList from database every time, because I have to preserve checkmarks in the list which are not contained in the database.

What is wrong in my code? How can I resolve this problem? How to invalidate the StateEvent data after availability of a new list from database?

Comment: I'm not sure if I had understood correctly, but interesting is why `GetList` is fired second time - it means that in `e.PageState` there is no *MemoryItem* - is it new Page?. Then maybe you have two separate pages and mixing them.

Comment: When I navigate to this list page, then the list should be read from the database, because of possible modfications in the db. After displaying details and going back with rootFrame.GoBack, there should be a memoItem in e.PageState to use. And it should be the last saved. But I do manipulate the BackStack for special reasons and maybe I go with GoBack not to the last but to an older version. That would explain the error. And Yes: that's the problem!

Comment: Yes, I would search for the cause of the problem there. I'm not sure how your app works but mabe you can consider using a `public static ObservableCollection<MemoItem>` in your app so it will be available along the whole app (maybe a singleton, that depends on your needs, or Lazy<> when you initialize it). Then you will have to worry only when your app is supspended/resumed. Observable will also have this advantage that there won't be need to set ListView's ItemsSource again and again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved now. It was actually a consequence of the back stack manipulation.

I have four basic pages in my program, for which a GoBack makes sense. But I do not want to go back deeper. (I do not think anyone wants to go back 20 or more steps, but the seemingly unlimited BackStack would allow that.The required memory consumption is not negligible.)

In order to clear the BackStack at selecting one of the basic pages, I had this:

```
    private void NavButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;

        if (b != null && b.Tag != null)
        {
            Type pageType = Type.GetType(b.Tag.ToString());
            if (pageType != null)
            {
                if (rootFrame.CurrentSourcePageType != pageType)
                {
                    rootFrame.Navigate(pageType, rootFrame); 

                    // No goBack for Basic Pages
                    if (testBasicPage(pageType))
                    {
                        while (rootFrame.BackStackDepth > 1)
                        {
                            rootFrame.BackStack.RemoveAt(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

That worked fine until I came across the problem with SaveState / Load State.

Now I first empty the BackStack and then navigate to the target page. That works.

```
    private void NavButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;

        if (b != null && b.Tag != null)
        {
            Type pageType = Type.GetType(b.Tag.ToString());
            if (pageType != null)
            {
                if (rootFrame.CurrentSourcePageType != pageType)
                {

                    // No goBack for Basic Pages
                    if (testBasicPage(pageType))
                    {
                        while (rootFrame.BackStackDepth > 0)
                        {
                            rootFrame.BackStack.RemoveAt(0);
                        }
                    }
                    rootFrame.Navigate(pageType, rootFrame); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```